# Iterating over keys of nested dictionary and adding tabs

Tags: python

I have a nested dictionary like this {"step1": {}, "step2": {"step3": {"step4": {}},'step7':{}}},Now i need to recursively iterate over the nested dictionary and create a list of keys of nested dictionary with tabs prepend to it.

```
new_d={"step1": {}, "step2": {"step3": {"step4": {}},'step7':{}}}
other_list=[]
child=False
tabb='\t'
def put_tabs(d):
  global tabb,child
  for k, v in d.iteritems(): 
      if v:
          if child:
              other_list.append("{0}{1}".format(tabb,k))
              tabb+='\t'      
          else:
              other_list.append("{0}".format(k))
          child=True
          put_tabs(v)
      else:
          if child:
              other_list.append("{0}{1}".format(tabb,k))

          else:
              other_list.append("{0}:".format(k))
          child=False
put_tabs(new_d)
print other_list

# Expected output ['step2', '\tstep7', '\tstep3', '\t\tstep4', 'step1:']
# current ouput ['step2', '\tstep7', 'step3', '\t\step4', 'step1:']
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is a function that will print the keys of a nested dictionary with indentation:

```
def indent_dict(d, indent=0):
    for key, value in d.iteritems():  # python 2
    # for key, value in d.items():    # python 3
        print("\t" * indent + str(key))
        if isinstance(value, dict):
            indent_dict(value, indent + 1)
        else:
            print("\t" * (indent + 1) + str(value))
```

for your input

```
new_d = {"step1": {}, "step2": {"step3": {"step4": {}}, "step7": {}}}
indent_dict(new_d)
```

it outputs:

```
step1
step2
    step3
        step4
    step7
```

(this is more or less the indenting function for xml from [here](https://effbot.org/zone/element-lib.htm)).

Comment: step4 is child of step3  which is internally child of step2 ,so two tabs for step4

Answer (score 0):

```
new_d={"step1": {}, "step2": {"step3": {"step4": {}},'step7':{}}}

def fn(d, counter):
    for k, v in d.items():
        yield '\t' * counter + k
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            yield from fn(v, counter + 1)

out = []
for p in fn(new_d, 0):
    out += [p]

print(out)
```

Prints:

```
['step1', 'step2', '\tstep3', '\t\tstep4', '\tstep7']
```

Answer (score 0):

As you said already a simple recursion will do:

```py
def put_tabs(d, level=0):
    rv = []
    prefix = '\t' * level
    for key in d:
        rv.append(prefix+key)
        if type(d[key]) == dict and len(d[key]) > 0:
            rv.extend(put_tabs(d[key], level=level+1))

    return rv

d = {"step1": {}, "step2": {"step3": {"step4": {}}, "step7": {}}}
print(put_tabs(d))
# ['step1', 'step2', '\tstep3', '\t\tstep4', '\tstep7']
```